# Do I have to cite 'lme4' when using 'lmerTest'?

Tags: r

I am using `lmerTest` to run linear mixed models (LMM) to get the p-values. However, in the articles I have written, they will show both `lme4` and `lmerTest`. Then I am not sure if I also have cite `lme4` when I use only `lmerTest` to run LMM models.

Do you have any idea about this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

lmerTest basically offers a bunch of convenience functions on top of lme4. The actual important software is lme4, which implements the model framework. You should definitely give the reference for lme4 as specified in `citation("lme4")`:

> Douglas Bates, Martin Maechler, Ben Bolker and Steven Walker (2014).
>   lme4: Linear mixed-effects models using Eigen and S4. R package
>   version 1.0-6. http://CRAN.R-project.org/package=lme4

This is not only important for giving well deserved attribution, but also to state the lme4 version number.

Comment: +1, wholeheartedly agree with giving version number. In my field this is often neglected.

Comment: +1 and a 3rd possibly important reason to cite the package is that R comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. So, even though we are fairly confident the algorithm is correct, we need to make the methods transparent so that, should any well understood peculiarity arise in the future, we can retrospectively ascertain the validity of your results now.

Comment: @AdamO I believe that point is valid for most software tools. There were well known bugs in Excel for years and I don't think Microsoft reimbursed anyone.

Comment: Okay. So I will cite both lme4 and lmerTest. Thanks very much Roland.

Comment: @NickStauner Thank you for your suggestion. Sorry for haven't done this for many questions I have posted as I am very new to this website, but now I know that I can do it. (I always wonder who people give me vote and how I can vote for other people)